# How can i fix this?

Tags: apt, updates, mono

```
ryan@Ryans-Gaming-Pc:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for ryan: 
N: Ignoring file 'mono-xamarin.listclear' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'sudo' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
ryan@Ryans-Gaming-Pc:~$
```

I was wanting to do an update and i recently tried to see if i could install Microsoft silver-light to watch netflix and it froze and did nothing when i tried to install moonlight and now it doesn't think sudo is in the source list. Please help thanks for your time.

Comment: Aside from this problem, you can't install moonlight any more, and you don't need to, to watch Netflix.

Comment: Please, always put a title that describes your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems in your sources list, as the error messages are telling you.

Remove `mono-xamarin.listclear` from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` by typing in a terminal `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.listclear`  If you think this file has some use, you could `sudo mv` it to another directory instead.

Next edit `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list` to remove the error it is complaining about.  `sudo` should not be in this file.  If you don't know why this file is in your sources directory, either delete it or move it somewhere else.  If you know that it needs to be there, edit your question (do not post as a comment or answer) and show the contents of this file, and I will help with editing it.

Comment: says permission is denied for some reason even though I'm the super user.

Comment: This is what it says when i do the second step: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
bash: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list: Permission denied

Comment: You need to edit with a text editor like `nano`. The command would be `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`

Comment: Oh okay sorry I'm not really a person who knows a lot of UNIX/Linux based codes cause I have had Ubuntu 16.04 for around 4 months sorry if i made you upset cause i don't know this stuff.

Comment: Also thanks It's working now thanks to you hopefully this this won't happen again and i also now know what to do if it happens again thank to you.

Comment: Great news! You didn't make me upset, sorry if I sounded that way.

Comment: However, check out this article, you don't need to do anything to watch netflix. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/03/netflix-finally-adds-support-firefox-linux

Comment: yeah i didn't know this cause the last time i had a Linux OS i had "Linux Mint" and had to install it many ways and i thought it was the same for Ubuntu but it apparently isn't.

Comment: Anyways thanks you saved me from doing another reinstall of Ubuntu and you are better than the stupid Microsoft tech support when i had problems before i had Ubuntu. Thanks and have a good day and don't stop helping people.